# what is the correct translation for the indoor playground attraction called a "ball pit", google gives: 球坑

Tags: translation

My son is working a project for his dual language immersion 2nd grade class; is 球坑 intelligible, as in: "这是我的球坑。" ?

I am always very concerned that the automated translation stuff will present something that ends up being slang or offensive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[波波池](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%B3%A2%E6%B3%A2%E6%B1%A0)

> 波波池（英语：Ball pit或Ball pool）是一个凹陷的位置上布满彩色小胶球的池，这些球的直径一般不大于3吋（7.6厘米）。除了小胶球外，亦可以使用其他球体物，如气球。波波池通常是专供小朋友玩乐的地方。

Here's an example of use from [winshang](http://news.winshang.com/html/067/1725.html):

> 这种带着“寓教于乐”的主题式乐园，由于其具有科学教育的作用，对入园的小朋友有一定的门槛要求，并非简单的玩乐，需要家长陪同。一旦消费者进入审美疲劳，持续的内容创新和体验创新就会变成一个问题。其间，funmax也做了很多积极调整，如扩充儿童职业体验内容、增加更适合低龄孩童的挖沙、波波池等等。进入2020年，伴随着疫情防控的严峻，FUNMAX-EXPO暂停了营业。

Comment: that is cool, is the `波波` part sort of a loan word that is specific to ball (phonetically)? it seems like a lot of loan words with a bo1 sound usually use: 波...

Comment: Might be chiefly Cantonese.

Comment: Yes, I was from Hong Kong, 球 in Cantonese is colloquially  called 波 (ball) - a loan word

Answer (score 1):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_pit
>
> originally called "ball crawl" and also known as a ball pool or ball pon

[Google image search for 球坑](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%90%83%E5%9D%91&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00t73lJ723u8nyaeaM_8WiDCntN3g:1588010401846&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje65rfl4npAhXDK80KHXQGBYIQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1571&bih=756)

[image]

https://www.definitions.net/translate/ball%20pit/zh

Seems like 球坑 is an accepted term for 'ball pit' in Chinese

Answer (score 1):

波波池, 球池, 波波球池 and 海洋球池 are all acceptable. 球坑 not so much. 球坑 sounds like digging a hole in the ground and then burying balls in it.